# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Levenshtein'

Tags: python, pip, levenshtein-distance

I installed `Levenshtein` using pip and it's included in `pip list` packages. But when I run a python script, appears this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Levenshtein'

This is the `pip list`:

```
Cython (0.29.15)
docopt (0.6.2)
dyNET (2.1)
mosestokenizer (1.1.0)
numpy (1.16.6)
openfile (0.0.7)
pip (9.0.1)
python-Levenshtein (0.12.0)
setuptools (28.8.0)
toolwrapper (1.0.0)
uctools (1.0.2)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

The `gcc` is linked to the environment variables.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you install the module? Are you trying to run the script in the same venv that you install the module?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install python-Levenshtein==0.12.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following

```
$ pip show python-Levenshtein | grep Location
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

If the package location is not in the `sys.path` then that would cause the error.

Comment: I got ```['', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']``` after ```/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"```

Comment: but ```pip show python-Levenshtein | grep Location``` shows me nothing, but if I run ```pip list```it is present.

Comment: I add the package location to the ```sys.path```. Now I'm getting ```ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__levenshtein)``` , it's so frustrating.

Comment: Did you `pip install` using `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 -m pip`?

Answer (score 0):

try `from rapidfuzz import levenshtein`