# ImportError: No module named Levenshtein

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, levenshtein-distance

I have python-Levenshtein installed.

```
root@marcelo:~# pip show python-Levenshtein | grep Location
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
root@marcelo:~#
```

However, I got the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named Levenshtein
```

Here is the relevante part of script code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# encoding: utf-8
#
#
#  scriptLattes
#  Copyright http://scriptlattes.sourceforge.net/
#
#
import logging
import os
import shutil
import sys
import Levenshtein

SEP     = os.path.sep
BASE    = 'scriptLattes' + SEP
ABSBASE = os.path.abspath('.') + SEP
```

I found the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269283/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-levenshtein) posted here, but it not have a answer to solve my issue here.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you running the code with python3 or python2?

Can you run the following code and post output:
```import sys
print(sys.version)```

Comment: I run:
`import sys 
print("Python version") 
print (sys.version) 
print("Version info.") 
print (sys.version_info)`
and got 
`Python version 
2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 14 2019, 21:00:58) 
[GCC 7.3.0] 
Version info. 
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=16, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: `which python`? `which pip`? `python --version`? `pip --version`? `python -m pip show python-Levenshtein`?

Comment: Solved! A few yers a go I have installed Anaconda3. So, it is breaking the script. I purged Anaconda3, updated the PATH variables and all work again! Thanks. How I close the question?

Answer (score 1):

simply give
`pip install Levenshtein`
and you'll be good to go. Worked for me.